# Decrease size of HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am creating snippets of HTML that later I convert to PNG (I am using `IMGKit` to do this).

My current HTML markup looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
    <div class='snippet'>
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, even if I set the following CSS:

```
.snippet {
    width:160px;
    height:600px;
}
```

When inspecting the DOM, I noticed that the HTML element it is much wider than its contained DIV. I would like the HTML and Body tag to be exactly the size of that div, so that when I render to PNG the final width and height are 160x600.

What is the correct way of doing this in CSS? Do I need to add width and height attributes to both HTML and Body elements?

Comment: You can address the `<html>` and `<body>` tags directly in CSS although that seems an odd way to create images.

Comment: How are you converting them later to PNG?

Comment: That should set the height/width of the div as you've put. You may need to simply add `overflow: hidden;`. Got a fiddle?

Comment: @putvande I am using IMGKit.

Comment: I think your bug is laying somewhere outside the obvious relevant classes or elements that would be involved in this. I made a test with  the data you posted and it seems to be working fine for me. [FIDDLE] (http://jsfiddle.net/xM4Fd/)

Comment: @LOTUSMS in your test, the html tag width is bigger than its children. Ideally I would want that the HTML is as wider and higher as the DIV.

Comment: Sure. I did that as a reference. To check to see if the snippet was actually displaying 160 width. If you notice, I gave the body 320px and it looks twice teh size of the snippet div. The html has color just for even more reference the widths are working. It's what I do whenever I'm bug hunting in widths. I use this or border:1px solid red if i wan t to be less conspicuous

Comment: LOTUSMS, thanks for taking the time to comment. However, my question was actually how can I make HTML and BODY tags to get the exact same width/height than the DIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the size of the `<html>` tag. Its not possible. The html tag dimension is defined as the browser view-port. you can however change everything else by applying the css style: `display: inline-block;` like so:

```
body, div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Krimson, there is no way I can decrease the size of the HTML element? How do they create small HTML snippets then?

Comment: @HommerSmith I am pretty sure you cant decrease the html tag size. Where do you see the smaller html?